# Check if user is logged in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, rest, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am implementing a chat/inbox feature on my website.  When users are not logged in and receive a message from another user, the website will send an email to the recipient of the message.  However when the user is logged in it won't.

My questions is how do I tell whether a user is logged in or not?  For example, if a user is logged in and then closes the browser my backend wouldn't know anything.

Btw I'm building a Angularjs SPA with a restful API in Laravel 4.?

Comment: I think its better for implemnt this in Angularjs and not in php... in php you can do some "dumb" checking like the user is online if he was active in the last 2 mintues wich

Comment: how would I do this in angularjs?  My backend needs to check whether the user is logged in and then decide whether to send an email or not

Comment: listen there is 2 diffrents tasks in what you want to do... 1:find out if user is logged in or not(php Auth::check()).... 2: find out if the user is online or not for this task you need to use angularjs with for example websocket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using Ajax to **ping** the DB when the user is logged in. Add a `last_logged_in` column of type `Date`
So when the users are logging in they update their `last_logged_in` field to the current date. You can do this Ajax as often as you like (very minimal performance issues). To see if a user is logged in simply check the `last_logged_in` date and compare it to the current date minus some time (1 minutes)..

I would not suggest using it to email users because it may result in lots of spam.
You can use the `is_logged_in` field in addition but don't use it on it's own.

Answer (score 19):

**if you are using build-in Laravel Auth:**

```
if(Auth::check())
{
   //do something
}
```

**if you are using Sentry:**

```
if(Sentry::check())
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  If user A is messaging user B who is not logged in how do I tell whether user B is logged in?  I thought Auth::check only works for the current user i.e. the one sending the message that is logged in?

Comment: Hi, in that case, you need a column in your users table. i.e 'logged_in' , if a user logged in set it 1. And when they logged out, set it 0.

Comment: Check this column to check whether a user logged in or not

Comment: What if the user logs in closes their browser? What would changed the column to logged out?

Comment: You could simply execute a cron that runs every 5-10 minutes that will update the user if the session cookie no longer exists, and then in your session config, set expire_on_exit to true. You could also use Ajax when the window is closing to send a php request to your logout route.

Comment: You really should consider modifying the answer to reflect the original question. :)